# Try to understand better how to set out an effective sample size within the MetagenomSeq package in microbiome

Tags: r, microbial-genomics, 16rrna, microbiome

Cross-posted on biostars: https://www.biostars.org/p/9572744/

I am trying to understand better what number to be used and how to put it in the function MRcoefs within the Metagenomeseq package in R for calculating differentially expressed OTUs between two condition:
my code looks like:

```
MRcoefs(fit, coef = 2, group = 3, number = 143, eff = 5.5)
```

Here I am setting the eff argument to 5.5 because I have calculated the effectiv_size using this code:

```
Effective_size(fit)
```

which result in table of effective size for each feature (OTU), and then I got the mean of these

```
mean(Effective_size(fit))
```

which was 5.5
When I run this, it produced an error:
prop outside [0,1], I understand it should be between 0-1, but why ? is not that number in eff is the mean that I calculated which bring 5.5 ?
Also when I tried to run it with .5 as the document suggested as below :

```
MRcoefs(fit, coef = 2, group = 3, number = 143, eff = .5)
```

it run nicely, no error , but it produced the same OTUs as when I did not include eff, I was expecting that some OTUs will be removed as they were below this threshold

Could you please help me ?

Comment: Hi @MohamedSamir, firstly please put your code into coding blocks. Secondly, the package you are using is **Metagenomeseq** but the tag is **16S**. These are two different approaches, could you please clarify which you are using?

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I mean Metagenomeseq which is used for analysing 16S microbiome data. I mean MetagenomeSeq package

Answer (score 0):

Set `numberEff = True`

```
MRcoefs(fit, coef = 2, group = 3, number = 143, eff = 5.5, numberEff = True)
```

I suspect you've got the quantile value set, hence it will throw an error above 1.